# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero even after using python future module

Tags: python-2.7

I am facing an error while running a  github code. I think the code is perfect, But i think am facing some dependency issues.  Can anyone tell me what could possible be the reason behind this error. I am using python 2.7.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
.
.     
def time_step(self, xt):
    xt = np.reshape(xt, newshape=self.dimensions)
    ret_val = 0.
    self.buffer.append(xt)
    self.present.time_step(xt)
    if self.t >= self.buffer_len:
        pst_xt = self.buffer[0]
        self.past.time_step(pst_xt)
        if self.t >= self.present.theta + self.past.theta:
            ret_val = self.comparison_function(self.present, self.past,
                                               self.present.alpha)
    self.ma_window.append(ret_val)
    if self.t % self.ma_recalc_delay == 0:
        self.anomaly_mean = bn.nanmean(self.ma_window)
        self.anomaly_std = bn.nanstd(self.ma_window, ddof=self.ddof)
    if self.anomaly_std is None or self.t < len(self.ma_window):
        anomaly_density = 0
    else:
        normalized_score = (ret_val - self.anomaly_mean)/self.anomaly_std
        if -4 <= normalized_score <= 4:
            anomaly_density = CDF_TABLE[round(normalized_score, 3)]
        elif normalized_score > 4:
            anomaly_density = 1.
        else:
            anomaly_density = 0.
    self.t += 1
    return ret_val, anomaly_density
```

The code line which is giving error is the following,

```
normalized_score = (ret_val - self.anomaly_mean)/self.anomaly_std
```

Comment: Please show us your code :)

Comment: the code is huge, I am trying to figure out what sort of dependencies might be responsible for this error. Also if i use simple try exception statement in the error line am getting an error             class MGNG has no attribute '__mro__'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in `try except`, I used `0` as except value but you can change it per your needs:

```
try:
    normalized_score = (ret_val - self.anomaly_mean)/self.anomaly_std
except ZeroDivisionError:
    normalized_score = 0
```